# fitting k*x**2+n function with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have data:

```
0       315
0.159   284
0.321   246
0.47    202
0.631   164
0.786   136
0.958   102
1.104   74
1.307   42
1.461   17
1.524   10.9
1.6 4.  6
1.728   0
```

I have a code :

```
set xlabel "Zaporna napetost [V]"
set ylabel "Tok [pA]"
set yrange [-25:350]
set xrange [-0.1:1.8]
set xtics 0.3
set mytics 2
set mxtics 2
f(x)=k*x**2+n
fit f(x) 'D:\Petra\sola\praktikum\fotoefekt\365.txt' using 1:2 via k,n
plot 'D:\Petra\sola\praktikum\fotoefekt\365.txt' using 1:2 lc rgb 'black' t"UV" , \
f(x) lc rgb 'black' t""
```

And the fit i get is totaly of. Can anyone help.

Comment: Well, it seems that your data and your model function don't match at all.

Comment: do you have any suggestion which function would fit the best?

Comment: Looks like you have experimental data. That's no guessing for model functions, but you must know what values you measured and what the expected dependency is.

Comment: it is expected to be liner but it doesn't really look like that. so i wanted to find a better fit.

Comment: But that's not how you can handle such a case! You cannot change your physics because a fit might look better ;) Maybe you have some systematical error for higher x values (above 1.4), so you could ignore those values: `f(x) = a*x + b; fit [0:1.4] f(x) '365.txt' via a,b; plot '365.txt', f(x)`. Of course, you should know, where those deviations might originate from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have experimental data. As you stated in your comments, you expect the have a linear dependency. You cannot change your physics and change the fitting function, just because it might look better.

In your case you could e.g. skip the points above 1.4, if you have a good reason (e.g. systematic errors), but use a linear fit:

```
f(x) = a*x + b
fit [0:1.4] f(x) '365.txt' via a,b
plot '365.txt' title 'experimental data', f(x) title sprintf('fit with %.2f·x + %.2f', a, b)
```

[image]